# Issue while applying PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: security, magento, magento-1.9, patch

I am facing issue while Applying PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh in magento 1.9.2.4.
Found below message after apply the patch. I am not aware about the steps to resolve the issue ... Please help me to resolve the issue.

I have seen below link but this is not working for me.

[Patching Magento 1.9.2.0 with Security patch 9767](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/176946)

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 370 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 417 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 446 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 91 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 126 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 201 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 141 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 43 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 201 with fuzz 1 (offset 2 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 900
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
|index 22a2fe6..b600f74 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 925
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
|index bf6dfcc..6cab97a 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 93 with fuzz 2.
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 142 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 201 with fuzz 1.
patching file app/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 140 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1213 (offset -72 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 391 (offset -16 lines).
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 417 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 964 (offset -15 lines).
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 82 with fuzz 2.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 268 (offset -5 lines).
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 723 (offset 39 lines).
```

So the error is basically at file location :

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
```

Please suggest I should go for manual entry of the patching or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing PATCH\_SUPEE-9767\_CE\_1.9.3.0\_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56 on Magento 1.9.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478570/error-installing-patch-supee-9767-ce-1-9-3-0-v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56-on-magento-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hunk error normally came because it will not match the file lines. In this case you can do 2 things.

1. Replace those three files with new same version Magento setup and then try to install the patch using SSH.
2. Install the patch manually. Because its RWD files so it will not affect your site if you are using your own custom theme.

In this patch in front end only form key is added in checkout and cart files so you can do it manually.

Thanks.

Comment: This works for me, as I download page.xml and /multishipping/addresses.phtml fresh from magento 1.9.2.4 and given desired permission and re-run the patch. Thanks.

Comment: @Indian : could you pls help me, how can i solve patch 10266 error https://snag.gy/hWXebp.jpg