# Error installing PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56 on Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: security, magento, magento-1.9, patch

I'm getting the following error and have no idea why. All my extensions are properly installed to not effect any code code.

Any ideas?

```
sudo sh ./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh
./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 14: ./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 127: not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 14: ./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 127: not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 25: ./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 370 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 417 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 446 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 36 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/etc/config.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1281 (offset -4 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 406 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 96 with fuzz 2 (offset 14 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 302 with fuzz 2 (offset 29 lines).
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 711 (offset 27 lines).
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hunk error normally came because it will not match the file lines. In this case you can do 2 things.

1. Replace those mention error files with new same version Magento setup and then try to install the patch using SSH.
2. Install the patch manually.

In this patch in front end only form key is added in checkout and cart files so you can do it manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
The solution for me was next:

1. Check if you have 'downloader' folder in your project, if not (usually it is not under git) - download it (better from the current project, versions can be different);
2. Revert the previous version of this patch (description of the patch - "Note that you must revert SUPEE-9767 version 1 before deploying version 2.")
   ($ bash ./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh -R)
   and after that try to patch 2nd version.